# Table cut off in quote

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-editor

If you quote a table, it cuts off the first character in each row:

[image: <code>nAttach</code> instead of <code>onAttach</code>]

Interestingly enough, it will consume back ticks before they can become code formatting.

---

Note that prepending any character provides a quick fix for this bug.

---

Copy and paste this for quick testing:

```
>method|description
-----|----
onAttach(Activity)  |  it is called ...
 onCreate(Bundle) |   It is used...
`onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)`  |  creates and returns...
*`onActivityCreated(Bundle)`  |  It is invoked...
o  |  It provides....
```

Comment: What if you put a `> ​` at the beginning of each line? (i.e. non-lazy)

Comment: @JF This is not how I expect quoting to work, and many users may not realize quoting messes up things. If I was quoting an unattributed table (instead of replacing an unattributed image with an attributed text table), I probably would have failed to notice this bug.

Comment: Yeah. I can see that.

Comment: Working with tables must be new for the SO team :) I bet there is some bad GREP in there.

Comment: Adding a space between the `>` and the table header does not solve the problem, but does remove one more character from the start of each row. Adding `>` to each row solves the problem, but it seems lists require an extra newline to avoid swallowing up the next row. Interesting!